# Bitcoin 2.0 offline transcation

Tags: blockchain

The biggest weakness of bitcoin is also it's biggest strength, ie, relying heavily on the **online** block-chain to confirm any transactions. The word **Online** is a very interesting word. For an individual, being **online** mean the power to access the world, but for your hard-earned money, constantly being **online** is more a liability than an asset. For starter, you can't spend your money while not being **online**, even if you are a millionaire. So it's a simple question. Why doesn't the block-chain have an offline functionality? Instead of getting confirmation by strangers around the world and while paying them a fee, Why not have an offline-password-based confirmation schema?

Being able to use your hard earned cash both Online and Offline is a huge deal. Or isn't it?

Comment: I think everyone agrees this would be great if there were a way to do it that was (1) secure (2) efficient (3) maintains the decentralized nature of the currency.  But nobody has found one yet.  It's not just the developers being lazy or ignorant of what users want. Whatever the "offline-password-based confirmation schema" is that you have in mind, I will bet a lot that it has some flaws that don't satisfy these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the block-chain have an offline functionality?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

Point.